# How to apply bootstrap style in dompdf

Tags: php, jquery, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm using bootstrap grid to display and i want that my client download it in pdf so for that i'm using dompdf but dompdf is not able to apply bootstrap style. I cannot go back and turn my bootstrap grid to basic html tables and using different plugin to convert to pdf i found them difficult and time consuming(especially in installing composer and then updating i'm new ) is there any way out so that i can easily apply bootstrap style to my pdf

```
   $pr_dt=$_POST['hid'];//div elements which i want ot convert them to pdf and also contain bootstap lib link
   include_once("../assets/converter/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
   $dompdf =  new DOMPDF();
   $dompdf->load_html($pr_dt);
   $dompdf->render();
   $dompdf->stream("MRA.pdf");
```

or at least  is there any online converter for bootstrap grid to html tables

Comment: dompdf's CSS support is still a little lacking for something as complex as Bootstrap. You can get a basic design working, but more complicated designs are not likely to produce the desired results. If you provide a sample of the HTML we can try to tweak the CSS to get better results.

Comment: What you probably want is a headless browser, like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). It does require installation on the server, but since it's based on webkit it produces results as good as any modern web browser.

Comment: sorry but i don't access to my webserver for installation i can only upload my files when its done

Answer (score 4):

Put All CSS codes in same page . Do **not** refer CSS to external link .

Work with inline tags like *margin* ,*padding* ,*top* and etc.

Comment: Yeah....This is basically the solution that helps your users download pdf faster

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure dompdf can find your CSS files. You can do this with `set_base_path`, for example:

```
$dompdf->set_base_path("/www/public/css/");
```

You also need a to specify the CSS file, something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
<body>
...
```

Comment: now i'm getting Cannot find Font class 
fontmetrics_cls.php on lin 346

Comment: Make sure your dompdf is setup correctly. Check your setup.php and it should tell you what's wrong, for example: http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/setup.php

Comment: DOMPDF_PDF_BACKEND is CPDF should i change this

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same challenge and solved it by:
Add the bootstrap.min.css code at the  tag at the top of the page. 
N.B bootstrap 3 works best.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Include before the html code:

```
        $html = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

'in response to the now i'm getting Cannot find Font class fontmetrics_cls.php on line 346'

This happens as you need to add Dompdf to your applications config to include modules. In zf2 its application.config.php in the modules section 
I hope that helps as I went hours looking for that without any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Bootstrap v3.3.6`, it is working with DomPDF,
I have tested

Answer (score 0):

```
$content .= '<style>
'.file_get_contents("./bootstrap.min.css").'
</style>';
```

Add this into your html code.. it will print the raw css into the html code

Answer (score 0):

check this.
if you ned bootstrap in multi projects ,create a file php with this.

```
<?php
     echo '
       <style>
               todo el codigo de bootstrap
       </style>
    ';
?>
```

and in your code add a `include 'bootstrap.php';`